# 503 error is seen even after the app is fully deployed in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-503

We start our Python App in GAE using Google Cloud Deploy tool (gcloud app versions start ..). 503 error is seen even after the app is started in Google App Engine (i.e. the tool returns but when you hit the browser the following error is seen for quite some time). This downtime is not acceptable, what could be done here?

https://mycompany-app.appspot.com/

503. That’s an error.
     The service you requested is not available at this time.
     Service error -27. That’s all we know.

Comment: There can be many reasons, IMHO you'll have to give a lot more info about your app and what you're doing to get some useful answers...

Comment: does it eventually work?  or never?  Like Dan said above, I think we need more info.

Comment: What do the stackdriver logs say ?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I will add more information when I see this error again from the logs

Comment: @jcjones1515 It eventually works but is down for a brief moment which is not acceptable since this is a production system.